# facebook access_token of user

Tags: facebook, access-token

Is it possible that we can request for our facebook access_token and then give it to the third party?

I am planning to make a site that the users are able to save favorite facebook post and then I will save that to my site.

What do you think? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

See, the whole idea about using access tokens, is security. They're not meant to be given away like that.

As far as the site where you can save Facebook posts is concerned - it sure is possible. But could you elaborate a little more, on what you're looking at?

Comment: this is the flow of my perpective. At first, user_Ben will copy the link of the post he likes (let say Anna_post), and then submit it to my site. All I need is user_Ben access_token so I can display to him Anna_post on my website. What do you thik? can I request for user_Ben access_token?

Comment: Okay. I get it now. So here's the thing. It's a better idea to have Ben log into your site first, and provide the read_stream permission. You save the access token that you get. Ben then gives you the link of the post. You can then save that link, and show it later to Anna, by using the access token you stored earlier. Does that sound like it solves the problem?

Comment: I think you misinterpret at the part of Anna. I just need Ben access_token so he can view Anna's post right? :) thanks for entertaining my question.

Comment: Oh. My bad. I totally get it now. Yes. It's possible. A little complicated, but possible. Don't mention it!

Comment: Thanks @Rudi Mk ... now I'm going to pursue it!